# Struts 2 - Removing action from url

Tags: java, struts2

I have been searching for methods to remove `.action` suffix extension from the url in Struts 2. I have gone through various variations of similar codes. For eg:

```
<constant name = "struts.action.extension" value = ""/>
```

and

```
<constant name = "struts.action.extension" value = ","/>
```

but to no effect. My site it keeps on redirecting to `/xyz.action` and gives an error of Resource not Found when I specify the url to be `/xyz`. I am using `Struts 2.2.3`. Can some one please tell me what to do to achieve this? Is there a possibility that the problem pertains to web.xml rather than struts.xml?

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

there are various other filters like session, email, transaction etc. and a servlet.

Comment: You could post the web.xml, but how the url is created? Do you use any other configuration files?

Comment: Please show your web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the ***url-pattern*** of the *filter-mapping* for the *StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter* in ***web.xml*** accordingly:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
  </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

(while normally it would be something like `<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>` or `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>` )

Doc: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/webxml.html

Comment: Hi Andrea! I am using a FilterDispatcher. I don't know about the StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter and what changes will it bring along with the URL change. An insight would be really helpful.

Comment: Than that is the error ;) [Since struts 2.1.3, FilterDispatcher is deprecated and StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter should be used](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html)

Comment: Btw you are not using THE Struts2 FilterDispatcher, but an external Filter... why using an external one instead of the Struts2 provided one (that is the one mentioned in my answer) ?

Comment: Okay so I will try StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter instead of FilterDispatcher. Also can you tell me whether my other settings in terms of <constant name value/> is correct?! And should I add a <rule>  using regex for URLRewrite?

Comment: Well I tried this and it worked... But the counter problem that is occurring is that I have lost my styling related to the page.

Comment: Perfect... you only need to configure excludePattern: `<constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/js/.*, /css/.*, /img/.*"/>` read more here: http://www.mail-archive.com/user@struts.apache.org/msg97184.html

Comment: thanx it worked even without it... static contents are now working fine...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change in struts.xml as follows:
By giving value"whatever" instead of "," 
ANS:

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value="whatever" />
```

Comment: Wow I never knew that Struts was so advanced!