# Struts 2 remove .action extension when redirect

Tags: java, redirect, struts2

Before starting, I'm sorry for my bad English, because English is not my first language. However, I have a problem with Struts 2 redirecting.

One part of my `Struts.xml` file is like this:

```
<package name="login" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="login" class="Action.loginAction">
        <result name="success" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">search</param> 
            <param name="namespace">/</param> 
        </result>
        <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

I have a `loginAction` that's responsible for logging in the user (no matter what is the content of this file). When the result of this action is `success`, I want to redirect to `search` action. Everything works fine, but my problem is, when I redirect to `search` action, the URL looks like this: `http://localhost:8080/MyWebApplication/search.action`

I want to have the `.action` removed from the URL, when redirecting to a particular action. What do I need to change to fix this?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160838/struts-2-removing-action-from-url

Comment: What a version of Struts do you use?

Answer (score 0):

By default struts2 framework will add .action you can override it by following configuration.

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=""/>
```

For ref:
http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/mapper/DefaultActionMapper.html

Comment: In this way, all js/css/image files will be considered as struts action and leads to a 404 errors